# Looking for a localStorage solution for simple table editing (page HTML included)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, javascript-objects, getelementbyid

I'm trying to build a 'tool' (beina mainpage with a menu, and a few subpages with some tables) for composing answers from prewritten bits for me and my work collagues. I'd do with just html editing on my own, but I'd like to make a couple of improvements on it for them... not that I know how to, despite trying.

I found a nice, editable table on stack/jsfiddle and can get it to run, yet the saving doesn't work.
It allsows for editing of cells, and adding rows. Delete I don't care much for.

I tried to copy with some form of getElementBy, but failed miserably.

Trying to auto-add the buttons in the next row doesn't work either.

Here's codepen. https://codepen.io/pen/?template=vYGRKvZ

Any input will be appreciated.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


<style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
  .editable{ background:#EAEAEA}

.clEdit
{
width : 200px; /*Try chaging it as per need*/
overflow : hidden; /*  try scroll with more height  */
height : 15px;/*Try chaging it as per need*/
}

</style>

<script id="insert"></script>


</head>
<body>
```

```
        <table class="table table-striped" id="ConTable" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>tag</th>
              <th>button(s)?</th>
              <th>text to copy</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">welcome</div></td>
              <td><button id="copy">©copy next</button><br><button id="save">☑save all</button></td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">lorem ipsum</div></td>
            </tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">another tag</div></td>
              <td><button id="copy">©copy next</button><br><button id="save">☑save all</button></td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">lorem ipsum</div></td>
            </tr>
               <td>3</td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">welcome</div></td>
              <td><button id="copy">©copy next</button><br><button id="save">☑save all</button></td>
              <td><div class="clEdit" contenteditable="true">lorem ipsum</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


   <button id="copy">©copy next</button>
   <button id="save">☑save all</button>
     <button id="add">Add Rows</button>
      <button id="del">Delete Rows</button>
   
<div id="divCon">


</div>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[


$(".clEdit").prop('contenteditable',true);

//Try with hover replace click with hover

       $(".clEdit").hover(function(e){
        
        $(this).prop("title",$(this).html());
      
       });

var idFirstCol = 3;
$("#add").click(function(){
//LOGIC TO ADD ROW TO TABLE

var trRow = "<tr><td>"+ ++idFirstCol
+ "</td><td>"+ "SecondColValue" +"</td><td><div class='clEdit'>"+ "ThirdColValue" +"</div></td>s     <td> "+ "LastColValue"+" </td></tr>";


$("#ConTable").append(trRow);
$(".clEdit").hover(function(e){
        
        $(this).prop("title",$(this).html());
      
       });
       $(".clEdit").prop('contenteditable',true); });

//]]></script>

<script>
// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
  window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
    height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    slug: "8mt6d7bz"
  }], "*")
}

// always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
window.name = "result"
```

```
</body></html>
```

Comment: Give your table an `id` and use `localStorage.setItem("content", document.getElementById("table").innerHTML);`. Then whenever you open up the app for a second time just use `document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("content");`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save the table data to localStorage, this is how I would do it.

I'd use an array of key-value pairs, this is what it would look like...

```js
const tableDataArray = [
  {
    tag: 'some tag stuff',
    buttons: 'some button stuff',
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    tag: 'some more tag stuff',
    buttons: 'some more button stuff',
    text: 'some more text'
  }
];
```

When dealing with localStorage I would...

1. grab the array from local storage, if it exists... or I would create an array in localStorage (array typically is empty but you can put some default rows in if you want)
2. Populate the table with the data saved in the array I just got from localStorage.
3. When a user adds or deletes a row, I would add/delete that row from the array in your code, not from localStorage.
4. When a user hits 'save' I would then save the array from the code to local storage, overwritting what was in localStorage with the new updated array.

FOR #2.
After grabbing the saved array from localStorage, I'd loop through the array adding each element in the object to the respective column.

```js
for (let i = 0, i < tableDataArray.length, i++) {
  // determine which row you're adding to then...
  secondColValue = tableDataArray[i].tag;
  thirdColValue = tableDataArray[i].buttons;
  lastColValue = tableDataArray[i].text;
}
```